# Is it correct to write "is not focus on"?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I've read the sentence:

> The board of my company **is not focus** on employees

and I am wondering if it is correct.

I'd rather write "*is not focus**ed** on*" or "*is not focus**ing** on*".

I do not find any case where "*is not focus*" is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That might've been a typo. It sounds very odd to me. 
both of your examples are perfectly fine and correct.

> **"is not focused on" or "is not focusing on".**

Comment: Or _does not focus on_.

Comment: Or *is not to focus on*. If it is, for example, the owner of the company speaking.

Answer (score 6):

You’re right, that’s not standard English, and both your corrections sound good, depending on the context. I would assume someone made a typo or doesn’t understand when to use participles in English. If it is the latter, I have seen a lot of native speakers make similar mistakes, like “It is suppose to”. Maybe it’s because when speaking, a “t” sound following an “s” sound is often elided or pronounced too quickly or softly to be heard.

Answer (score 5):

For the noun ***board*** the correct tense of verb "to focus" would be **focuses** 
 or **does not focus** for the present.

So you are correct in that ***is not focus*** is incorrect. Both of your examples sound correct.

Comment: Is not focuses?

Comment: No, you would have to move ***not*** to the end of focuses.

Comment: “The board focuses” but “The board does not focus”.

Comment: You Are Correct.

Comment: @Mixolydian : But note also "The board does focus" and "The board does not focus".

Comment: Those are both correct, though “does focus” is usually used to contradict a negative statement: “It doesn’t focus.” “That’s not true, it does focus.”

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the correct should be "**does not focus on**" if we are speaking about focus in general, or "**is not focusing on**" if this it taking place for a period of time.

You could also say "**is not focused on**" if you convey a present situation likely to change. In my opinion, it has a slight "**yet**" to it.